# Converting a REST API get request to GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, graphql, rest

I have a REST API, shown below, that takes in a code param, search the database, return a result if the param exists, and redirect users to a long_url gotten from the database. How do I translate this to graphQL?

```
indexRoute.get("/:code", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const urlCode = req.params.code

    const url = await Model.findUrlCode(urlCode)

    if (url) {
      return res.redirect(url.long_url)
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json("No url found.")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).json("Server error")
  }
})

export default indexRoute
```

Comment: I moved from using REST to GQL recently. Really like it, would choose GQL over REST now but steepish learning curve and it's a completely different philosophy, so it doesn't really make sense to 'convert' a REST endpoint to GQL. I started with this thinking and it was a complete waste of my time

Comment: Check out the GQL playground - really helped me learn how it all works: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/graphql-playground/

Comment: Helps you get a feel for the structure and syntax of GQL and think differently from how you might be used to with REST

Comment: graphql returns JSON response, no redirects or any other browser-based behaviours ... you can return url within the response but client decides what to do with that info

Answer (score -1):

a very good resource with example,

https://blog.bitsrc.io/migrating-existing-rest-apis-to-graphql-2c5de3db

Comment: the link you have provided is dead